# Alpine 3.9 force to use python 3.6

Tags: python, docker, python-3.6, alpine-linux

Looks like current version of alpine 3.9 is supporting python 3.8, but I am using python 3.6 and can't upgrade to 3.8 soon. I was wondering if it is possible to force alpine to use python 3.6.

I tried following but no success:

`RUN apk add python36`

`RUN apk add python3.6`

Comment: use a different docker image, isn't that the point?

Comment: also you are probably looking for `python3` as you can see here --> https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=python3&branch=v3.9

Comment: @pms `python3` version on Alpine 3.9 is currently 3.6.9, so you should be good.

Comment: @valiano Yes you are right, but I noticed that anything from `edge` is polled into my alpine 3.9 as well. That's why default python version was 3.8. Just needed to keep a specific version of python as explained here: `https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management#Advanced_APK_Usage`

Answer (score -4):

1. You shouldn't use Alpine if possible, it risks obscure bugs and needing to compile libraries (https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/).
2. If you must use Alpine, you can use the `python:3.6-alpine` base image.

Comment: Thanks. I am using `https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management#Advanced_APK_Usage` convention for versioning of required softwares

Comment: lol alpine is one of the most widely used docker images known to the world